# Expo React Native Notifications addNotificationResponseReceivedListener is not firing when Notifee package is installed

Tags: expo, expo-notifications

I'm working on an Expo React Native App and was using the [expo-notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) library, however, one limitation is not being able to attach images. So I went for [Notiffe](https://notifee.app/) library and followed the installations step in [here](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/installation), fortunately I'm able to create local notifications and add images, but I encountered a new issue where the "addNotificationResponseReceivedListener" of the expo-notifications library is not firing any more, and a lot of the logic is dependant on it. Can any one help ?

exposdk: 49.0.0
"expo-notifications": "~0.20.1"
"@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2"

I noticed the [expo-notifications](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/) "addNotificationReceivedListener" function fires without any problems, and [Notiffe](https://notifee.app/) library consumes all the response events. The problem is we are relying on expo-notifications to handle push notifications from our backend.